# is there an option to display a selenium session in website

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to display a Python selenium session (which run a flow in some website) on my website so that the user can see the session that is running? I'm using the Django library.

Comment: Seems like it would be possible to serve up screenshots of the session.  Use a JS loop to update an <img> src.

Comment: I managed to add screenshots, but I want a better user experience and if possible, the ability to interact with it.